# HTTPS request timeout in nodejs

Tags: node.js, https, request

for some reason I'm getting a **read timeout** when requesting a **HTTPS** website. (Using node.js latest version)

Code:

```
var request = require('request');
request('https://twitchemotes.com/api_cache/v2/global.json',{timeout: 6000}, function (err, response, body) {
    if(err){
        console.log(err.code === 'ETIMEDOUT'); // logs true
        console.log(err.connect === true); //logs false
    }
    else console.log(body);
});
```

The weird thing is, this works on normal HTTP requests.

Any bit of help is really appreciated

Comment: I've run your code, its absolutely legit - no errors, and correct json in response. Your problem doesn't lie here.

Comment: Yep I just found the cause, for some reason it only works on Production Environment. I was on development

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason when you run your **express.js** application in **development** mode, the **request** module doesn't work with **HTTPS** requests.

I just changed the environment to **Production** and that solved my problem.

Comment: Yours answer is not clear. You've changed enviroment to production in express.js? Try to make it an answer which would help other users who will find it. 

Please write what was the real problem and maybe why changing this solved it.

Comment: Done. I don't know what else to mention on this.

Comment: Fair enought, now it has some value :)